# Another definite integral $\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^1\,\cos\, \left(\{nx\} \cdot \pi\right)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Consider $n$ a positive integer. Evaluate
>
> $$\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^1\,\cos\, \left(\{nx\} \cdot \pi\right)dx$$
>
> where $\{x\}$ stands for the fractional part of $x$.

*My ideas:* Whenever there is a limit/integral of trigonometric functions, I try to subtract their period and factor out the argument

$$\cos\, \left(\{nx\} \cdot \pi\right) = \cos\, \left(\{nx\} \cdot \pi-2n\pi\right)$$

and now write the fractional part $\{nx\} = nx-\lfloor nx\rfloor$.

$$\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^1\,\cos\, \left(n\pi(x-2)-\lfloor nx\rfloor\cdot \pi\right)dx$$

However here this does not seem to lead to anything fruitful. I feel like there must be some trick to split over smaller intervals depending on $n$ and $\pi$, but I can't see it. Does anybody have another suggestion?

Comment: The integrand is periodic with period $1/n$. Use this and the fact that $\{nx\}=nx$ over the domain $[0,1/n]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1}\cos\, \left(\{nx\} \cdot \pi\right)dx = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\int_{\frac{i}{n}}^{\frac{i+1}{n}}\cos\, \left(\{nx\} \cdot \pi\right)dx$$

Now we have to evaluate $\int_{\frac{i}{n}}^{\frac{i+1}{n}}\cos\, \left(\{nx\} \cdot \pi\right)dx = \int_{\frac{i}{n}}^{\frac{i+1}{n}}\cos\, \left( nx\pi-\lfloor nx\rfloor  \pi\right)dx = \int_{\frac{i}{n}}^{\frac{i+1}{n}}\cos\, \left( nx\pi-  i\pi\right)dx$ 
Which gives two different cases

$$\int_{\frac{i}{n}}^{\frac{i+1}{n}}\cos\, \left( nx\pi-  i\pi\right)dx = \begin{cases} 
-\int_{\frac{i}{n}}^{\frac{i+1}{n}}\cos\, \left( nx\pi\right)dx & i:\text{odd}\\
\int_{\frac{i}{n}}^{\frac{i+1}{n}}\cos\, \left( nx\pi\right)dx & i:\text{even}
\end{cases}$$

and $\int_{\frac{i}{n}}^{\frac{i+1}{n}}\cos\, \left( nx\pi\right)dx = \frac{1}{n\pi}\sin(nx\pi) \Bigl|_{\frac{i}{n}}^{\frac{i+1}{n}}=0$, Therefore $\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1}\cos\, \left(\{nx\} \cdot \pi\right)dx = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}((-1)^i\times0) = 0$.